# Leave class member field uninitialized

Tags: c++, destructor, unions

I am looking for a mechanism in C++ that would allow a class to *not* unconditionally destruct one of its member fields, and instead require explicit destruction.
In other words, an unmanaged std::optional class.

I have come up with the following:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Node {
  // ... a bunch of stuff ...
  Node* parent; // not related to data
  union {
    bool _dummy;
    T data;
  };
  Node() : parent(nullptr) {}
  Node(Node* p, T data) : parent(p), data(std::move(data)) {}
  ~Node() {
    // my invariant is: data is initialized iff parent is not nullptr
    if (parent) data.~T(); // data leaks if this is commented out
  }
};

int main() {
  std::string text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  Node<std::string> a;
  Node<std::string> b(&a, text);
  return 0;
  // no memory leak
}
```

Using `std::optional<T>` here would be redundant and make `Node<T>` bigger. Using a pointer is also not an option.

Is there a better option that doesn't require any extra space?
If not, does the ugly union have the correct semantics of initializing `data` iff I use the second constructor?

Comment: "But the exists boolean is actually something else (a pointer)" - You declared `exists` as a `bool`, so that's what it is. It is *not* a pointer.

Comment: Replace your union with `char data[sizeof(T)];` and then use placement new to optionally construct the object. There might be some allignment issues, I'm not certain how you work around those, but I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: So... you're trying to reinvent `std::optional` but save the space of one boolean because you have another way of determining whether the data is set or not? If so then simply look up a canonical example of a _tagged union_ online, use it, but swap the bool for your alternative.

Comment: @john `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> buffer`

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings that is exactly correct, but this tagged union has only one variant. I was just wondering if there was anything simpler in this case.

Comment: `std::aligned_storage` this looks a lot better and safer, thanks @MooingDuck @john

Comment: Note you'll probably also want to `=delete` the copy constructor and copy assignment since those are hard to implement.